Connect Budibase to SQL Server?
I have been trying to connect Budibase to SQL Server but all in vain. I have enabled the SQL Server Browser and SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS), however, I have failed to enable the SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS). I have restarted the service and database instance several times. I keep getting the error

Error creating datasource: Unable to connect: Failed to connect to localhost\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms.

I have tried enabling and disabling the Encrypt option too but I get the same result.

I am using SQL Authentication to log in. On my system, I login successfully. I have also enabled the TCP/IP for SQLEXPRESS. Unfortunately, nothing works for me. Are there any other suggestions or ways I can get these two to connect?


Suggestion: specify an instance name or specify a port, do not try to specify both. Unless you've really tweaked its configuration an SQL Server Express instance is unlikely to be listening on port 1433.

Where is Budibase actually running? If it's running in a Docker container or a Kubernetes pod then localhost is referring to the container/pod itself, not the machine where you've installed SQL Server Express. If you are running Docker Desktop on the same machine as SQL Server Express and Budibase is running in a Docker container within it, have you tried host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS yet?

Thank you for this. I am running Budibase from the browser. I specified the port 1433.

' I have failed to enable the SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS).'- that's because it's not available in sqlserver express..https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16 for what is and what is not in various sqlserver editions.

@P.Salmon thank you for this clarification. I thought I needed it enabled for the connection to be successful.
